# How to pass the JSON data into the textboxes Asp.net Ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I'm retrieving data from edit_retrun.aspx page. Data successfully return, I check through `alert(data.d);`  format came look like this to ajax success called method

```
[{"id":"464","fname":"dsf","age":"34"}]
```

but when I tried to pass the data into relevant textboxes it won't display the result atext boxeses no errors were displayed. what I tried so far I attached below.

these are the textbox to pass the data.

```
 $('#fname').val(data.fname);                        
 $('#age').val(data.age);
```

Ajax full code

```
 $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: 'edit_return.aspx/doSome',
         dataType: 'JSON',
         data: "{id: '" + id + "'}",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         success: function (data) {
         alert(data.d);    
         console.log(data.fname);
         $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
         isNew = false       
         $('#fname').attr('value', data.fname);
         $('#fname').val(data.fname);                        
         $('#age').val(data.age);

        },
```

edit_retrun.aspx page

```
 [WebMethod]
public List<Employee> doSome(int id)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=.; Initial Catalog = jds; Integrated Security= true;");
    string sql = "select * from record where id='" + id + "'";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dt);
    List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();

    employees = dt.AsEnumerable()
            .Select(x => new Employee()
            {
                id = x.Field<int>("id").ToString(),
                fname = x.Field<string>("name"),
                age = x.Field<int>("age").ToString(),
            }).ToList();
    return employees;
}
```

**Form Design**

```
<form  id="frmProject" runat="server">
        <div>
            <label class="form-label">First Name</label>     
           <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" class="form-control"  required />

        </div>
        <div class="form-group" align="left">
         <label class="form-label">Age</label>
            <input type="text" id="age" name="age" class="form-control"  required />
        </div>
        <div> 
           <input type="button" id="b1" value="add" class="form-control" onclick="addProject()" />

        </div>      
    </form>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do

```
JSON.parse(data);
```

then assign to textboxes.

Refer [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp) link.

Comment: The main change is returning `List<Employee>` in the method, only `JSON.parse` was not the helpfull!

Answer (score 1):

As you said when you `alert(data.d)` it gives:

```
[{"id":"464","fname":"dsf","age":"34"}]
```

Use this:

```
$('#fname').attr('value', data.d[0].fname);
```

Working Demo:

```js
var d= [{"id":"464","fname":"dsf","age":"34"}]

$('#fname').attr('value', d[0].fname);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="fname">
```

Comment: i tried that way but resut didn't displayed sir $('#fname').attr('value', data.d[0].fname);

Comment: `console.log(data)` what it gives?

Comment: Object  d: "[{"id":"464","fname":"dsf","age":"34"}]"         this is the console.log(data) result why couldn't pass the values in to the textboxes sir

Comment: is that trailing and ending `"` are there?

Comment: Just add a screenshot  of console.log(data) in the question

Comment: Object
d: "[{"id":"464","fname":"dsf","age":"34"}]"
__proto__: Object

Comment: i added the sceen shot above

Comment: Use JSON.parse (data) and then assign to textboxes.

Comment: @Hp_issei it's not a valid JSON string to parse! a string should '{name:"prash"}' not "{name:"prash"}"

Comment: so how can we correct sir please help me to correct

Comment: That's the issue you need to convert the string to json first then assign

Comment: i don't know how to convert can you write the code it is help ful for me

Comment: @ProgrammerHari can you try after replacing `return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(employees);` wth `return employees;` in aspx page behind?

Comment: I would suggest to send a valid JSON instead doing work around!

Comment: if i call return employees ; error displayed (local variable)List<Employee>employee

cannot implicitly convert type...

Comment: Change the return type method:`public static List<Employee> doSome(int id){}`

Comment: Now use the `console.log(data)`

Comment: sir you always great for me working thanks .. one doubt sir .asmx page or  .aspx   is best one do the json part  please expain that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185806/discussion-between-prashant-pimpale-and-programmer-hari).